# Is there a list of Ghidra's variable prefixes?

Tags: ghidra, decompiler

In Ghidra, the decompiler prepends various prefixes to variable names. For instance, `iVar1` is an integer. However, there are a lot of prefixes that aren't immediately obvious, find some below, but I'm looking for a complete dictionary if anyone knows where it is:

- `local_31`
- `auStack8320`
- `uStack4`
- `DAT_<addr>`

Comment: Maybe this [wikipedia article about hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) helps too.

Answer (score 9):

This is annoyingly hard to find the answer to. This is a good starting point, but I don't think I found everything yet.

1. Variable names

   1. From [Function.java](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/0cdc722921cef61b7ca1b7236bdc21079fd4c03e/Ghidra/Framework/SoftwareModeling/src/main/java/ghidra/program/model/listing/Function.java#L39):

      1. `param_`
      2. `local_`
      3. `local_res`
      4. `temp_`
   2. From [database.cc](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/0cdc722921cef61b7ca1b7236bdc21079fd4c03e/Ghidra/Features/Decompiler/src/decompile/cpp/database.cc#L2330) <-- this function has most (maybe all?) of the variable naming logic. There are multiple pieces of this function that I don't yet understand; I'm pretty confident there are additional variable naming conventions hiding in there.

      1. `unaff_retaddr`
      2. `unaff_`
      3. `in_`
      4. `param_`

         1. While also referenced in `Function.java`, I believe this is where the name is actually generated.
      5. `extraout_`
      6. `Var`

         1. Seems to usually be prefixed by something else (like `i` in your example)
   3. I think [this function in `varmap.cc`](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/0cdc722921cef61b7ca1b7236bdc21079fd4c03e/Ghidra/Features/Decompiler/src/decompile/cpp/varmap.cc#L407) is the one that creates stack variables, but I haven't yet confirmed.
2. Label names (from [SymbolUtilities.java](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/0cdc722921cef61b7ca1b7236bdc21079fd4c03e/Ghidra/Framework/SoftwareModeling/src/main/java/ghidra/program/model/symbol/SymbolUtilities.java#L44)):

   1. `SUB_`
   2. `LAB_`
   3. `DAT_`
   4. `UNK_`
   5. `EXT_`
   6. `FUN_`
   7. `OFF_`

Also useful, the [FindPotentialDecompilerProblems.java](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/0cdc722921cef61b7ca1b7236bdc21079fd4c03e/Ghidra/Features/Decompiler/ghidra_scripts/FindPotentialDecompilerProblems.java) script has some explanations for what some of these mean. Namely, some of the variants of `extraout`, `in_`, and `unaff_`.